# How to call a stored procedure from Oracle 11g Express Database using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, oracle11g

I know this question is asked too many times, I searched a lot, didn't find a single solution.

I am using Visual Studio 2012, Entity Framework 6.1.3, .NET 4.5, ASP.NET MVC 4 - application. The database and VS2012 connectivity is ok and I am able to use ADO.NET Entity Data Model `.edmx` to interact with database perfectly fine.

I have this simple table `CATEGORIES`. This table has two columns `CATEGORY_ID` and `CATEGORY_NAME`. The rows are:

```
CATEGORY_ID      CATEGORY_NAME
----------------------------------
    1            SELECT A CATEGORY
    2            Grocery
    3            Cosmetics
    4            Clothing
    5            Stationary
    6            Electronics
    7            Sweets
```

Please give me:

1. Oracle the database code example to create the procedure or function for this `CATEGORY` table.
2. Entity Framework code example to get rows from the procedure or function

Comment: Sorry the column values didn't come here correctly. So I'm providing again.
CATEGORY_ID : 1,2,3,4,5,6
CATEGORY_NAME: Grocery, Cosmetics, Clothing, Stationary,Electronics, Sweets

Comment: That's not how SO works - this ***isn't*** a code-writing service where you just dump your requirements and then demand the code - we'll **help** - if you have tried something yourself and you're stuck (then please **SHOW US** what you've tried so far, and explain **where** you are stuck) - but we **won't just write the whole code** for you!

Answer (score 1):

Ok after 4 hours of trying continuously without any rest I found the solution.
I have a Table in Oracle Database like this:

1. CATEGORY_ID       CATEGORY_NAME
2. 1          SELECT A CATEGORIE
3. 2            Grocery
4. 3            Cosmetics
5. 4            Clothing
6. 5            Stationary
7. 6            Electronics

For this I have a procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE GET_CAT_NAME(cat_id IN number, cat_name OUT 
varchar2)
IS
BEGIN
SELECT CATEGORY_NAME INTO cat_name 
FROM CATEGORY WHERE CATEGORY_ID = cat_id;
END;​
```

For this I have written code in C# like this:

```
using (OracleConnection objConn = new OracleConnection("DATA SOURCE=localhost:1521/XE; PASSWORD=irfan118406; USER ID=IRFAN_OMIDB22"))
        {
            OracleCommand objCmd = new OracleCommand("GET_CAT_NAME", objConn);
            objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            OracleParameter pout_descr = new OracleParameter("id", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 2000);

            //objCmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("id",OracleDbType.Varchar2,ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = 2;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add("cat_id",OracleDbType.Int32).Value = 3;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add("cat_name", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            objCmd.Parameters["cat_name"].Size = 20;

            try
            {
                objConn.Open();
                objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Response.Write(objCmd.Parameters["cat_name"].Value.ToString());

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.ToString());
            }

            objConn.Close();
        }
```

Code works perfectly without any error.

UPDATE:

```
objCmd.Parameters["cat_name"].Size = 20;
```

This line of code is super important, I was getting an error for continuous 3 hours: "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error calling a stored procedure", After putting the line of code, error disappeared and runs fine.